# Why can't I add Shared Binaries to TFS 2008 Source Control?

Tags: version-control, dll, tfs

I have 2 TFS projects on the same server (ProjectA and ProjectB). Both have the following structure...

- $/ProjectName/Dev/Source/ApplicationName/
- $/ProjectName/Dev/Source/SharedBinaries/

In ProjectA I can drag dlls into the ShareBinaries directory. In ProjectB, however, I cannot. TFS presents me with the 'Add to Source Control' dialog in which all the dlls are in the 'Excluded items' tab. Each dll has the description 'The item cannot be added because its destination path is cloaked.'.

I can see no difference between how the 2 projects are setup. Help, I'm stumped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edited the Workspace and added a specific mapping for:

- $/ProjectB/Dev/Source/SharedBinaries/*

I also then renamed the existing windows folder, added the SharedBinaries folder through TFS, checked it in then, finally, I was able to drag and drop the dlls. Not quite sure which bit of all that was the key though!

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at your workspace mappings.  It sounds like when you drag & dropped the files, Visual Studio created an extra workspace mapping.

Comment: +1 this is almost certainly the problem.  If not, do tell us how your workspace(s) are set up anyway, it affects future debugging inquiries.

Comment: Can you be more specific please?